# How can I change this loop so that it displays posts from the current tag

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I change this loop so that it displays posts from the current tag. Now it displays all posts. I need this to make the page tag.php

```
<?php
$current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 7, 
    'paged'          => $current_page 
    );
query_posts($args);

$wp_query->is_archive = true;
$wp_query->is_home = false;

while(have_posts()): the_post();
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="post_headline">
     <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
 </div>
 <?php
 endwhile;
 if (function_exists('custom_pagination')) {
    custom_pagination($query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi we need to pass tag name to the query post argument list, so I just modified the code, please try below code and let me know if any issues,

```
<?php
$current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
 $tag = get_queried_object();
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 7, 
    'tag' => $tag->slug,
    'paged'          => $current_page
    );
query_posts($args);

$wp_query->is_archive = true;
$wp_query->is_home = false;

while(have_posts()): the_post();
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="post_headline">
     <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
 </div>
 <?php
 endwhile;
 if (function_exists('custom_pagination')) {
    custom_pagination($query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Tell me, do I need to do the reset at the end of the loop ?

Comment: mean it <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>  @Ashkar

Comment: No.. No need of it. No other loops are here right? So no problem

Comment: On this page, no more query_posts loop, but on the other there, then do not need to do the reset ? @Ashkar